# print the value to textarea,

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner and self learner. This might be easy question but it is creating some problem to me. I think I missed something somewhere.

When I write some text in `textarea` and hit Find and replace button(leaving other two fields empty), the value captured from `textarea` should appear in the `textarea` itself and error message should appear outside the `textarea`. `textarea` should not be blank. I think message are working fine.

I am not sure if the problem is with the button or action='' in form.

```
<?php
//find and replace string
//using str_replace(), takes three parameters, $findword, $wordtoreplace, $userinput

if(isset($_POST['text']) && isset($_POST['find']) && isset($_POST['replace'])){
    $paragraph=nl2br(htmlentities($_POST['text']));
    $find_string=$_POST['find'];  //assign the value to be found to the variable
    $replace_string=$_POST['replace']; //assign the value to be replaced

    if(empty($paragraph)){
      echo 'No text to search for.';
    }
    elseif(empty($find_string)){
      echo 'Enter some text to find.';
    }
    elseif(empty($replace_string)){
      echo 'Enter some text to replace with.';
    }
    else{
      echo str_replace($find_string, $replace_string, $paragraph);
   }
}
?>
<form action='' method='POST'>
   <textarea name='text' rows=20 cols=100 value='<?php echo $paragraph; ?>'></textarea
   <br />
   <label>Search For</label>
   <input name='find' value='<?php echo $find_string; ?>'></input>
   <br />
   <label>Replace with</label>
   <input name='replace' value='<?php echo $replace_string; ?>'></input>
   <br />
   <button>Find and Replace</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<textarea>` doesn't have the `value` attribute. Provide the content like this:

```
<textarea name='text' rows='20' cols='100'><?php echo $paragraph; ?></textarea>
```

Btw, the closing bracket of `</textarea` was missing

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the output in the midle of textarea open and close tag:

```
<textarea name='text' rows=20 cols=100><?php echo $paragraph; ?></textarea>
```